# VB.Net Copying Text File content as it continiously updates itself

Tags: vb.net

So I have this log file from a Discord JS Bot I'm running, and I'm trying to make a Visual Basic copy of the log file contents in a textbox as it updates itself. And every 10 seconds or so, clear the text file content.

Comment: Seems vague???  I don't even see a question.  What exactly is the problem you're having?  We're not a code writing service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use an infinite loop, first add

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
```

Then:

```
Dim fileContent
Do
  fileContent = File.ReadAllText("FILEPATH")
  TextBox1.Text = fileContent 
  TextBox1.Refresh()
  Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
Loop
```

Replace `TextBox1` with the name of Text box control name.

Comment: it works properly that it sends the text content to the textbox! But that is only when I stopped my bot from logging the text. Is there really no way to still read it despite being edited real time? If theres not then I can close my problem as solved ^^ thanks again btw

Comment: @NathanielJorge windows prevents an application from reading a file when another process is writing into it.

Comment: thanks for the reply again, I understand now. I read through it as well to understand more. Thank you for the help ^^